# Public files marked as unlisted on Google Drive can't be retrieved via the API

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I have two files, one is marked as fully public and one is marked as unlisted (i.e. only those with a link can load it).

Public and listed: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bzim72JjnlIWRFlURmRrX3N6NEE/edit

Public and unlisted: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bzim72JjnlIWZHBwSFF0STRNNGc/edit

From everything that I've read in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-sharing#types_and_values), I should be able to retrieve the metadata for both files via the API with an api key. However, I can only retrieve the file that is fully public. Why?

Here's my test code that you can copy and paste into a javascript console:

```
//text.txt, open to everyone
//https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bzim72JjnlIWRFlURmRrX3N6NEE/edit
var xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr1.open("get", "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0Bzim72JjnlIWRFlURmRrX3N6NEE?key=AIzaSyDo66jOFuHllu3r3PwKcZaUd7N9ho9l9WU");
xhr1.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr1.readyState === 4){
        //will be true (status 200)
        console.log("text.txt metadata retrieved? " + (xhr1.status === 200));
    }
};
xhr1.send();

//text2.txt, open to just those with link
//https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bzim72JjnlIWZHBwSFF0STRNNGc/edit
var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr2.open("get", "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0Bzim72JjnlIWZHBwSFF0STRNNGc?key=AIzaSyDo66jOFuHllu3r3PwKcZaUd7N9ho9l9WU");
xhr2.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr2.readyState === 4){
        //will be false (status 404 Not Found)
        console.log("text2.txt metadata retrieved? " + (xhr2.status === 200));
    }
};
xhr2.send();
```

Comment: I didn't find anything in the linked part of the documentation that mentions that a key is sufficient for authentificaton. What I've found is this: [**Requests to the Drive API must be authorized using OAuth 2.0 credentials**](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/auth/web-client)

Comment: API keys are part of the standard Google Drive API query parameters: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/query-parameters Additionally, the guide on api keys says you can use them when "Data that the data owner has identified as public, such as a public calendar or blog." https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#usingkeys